# kubectl hangs when running python with restart=Never

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubectl

I am running the command:

```
kubectl run testbox -it --rm --restart=Never --image=python:buster -- python3
```

which will launch a python session and then I input `exit()` to quit the session. But the session hangs forever there. If I do `kubectl get po testbox` I can see the pod is already completed.

Then if I hit `enter` key the console will then output:

```
E0826 22:43:38.790348 1551782 v2.go:105] EOF
```

I noticed that this will not happen if I set `--restart=Always`. Not sure if it is expected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar issue posted on `kubectl` GtiHub page ([run commands don't return when using kubectl 1.22.x #1098](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1098)), created 3 days ago. Currently awaiting triage.

This is most probably a bug in *1.22* version of `kubectl`. If this issue causes you problems, I suggest downgrading to *1.21*, as this bug does not occurs in older versions.

Comment: Thank you @p10l ! Downgrading the client did make it work!